# Excel Power Query; How to merge values and pivot the questions

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a user who has done a survey twice. I would like to have a new table where instead of one user value per question the user is represented twice in the first column, and the other columns are the questions with the answers filled out on to the user lines.

I am just not succeeding. What should I exactly do?

[image: http://prntscr.com/hus9hb]

Comment: I'm sorry but i am still unclear what you are asking. Can you demonstrate the actual behaviour and the desired behaviour? I am wondering if you are referring to table fill down or perhaps appending tables but still not sure.

Comment: To pivot - you highlight the column(s) you want to pivot and you go to the transform > Any column > Pivot Column

Comment: Hey! I should have explained it much more easily.. Here you see a screenshot of what I have and how I would like it to have;

http://prntscr.com/hv45sz

Comment: Looks like you want to pivot questions and answers for user? What happened to User1 question 1 in the second survey completed?

Comment: Again why is one question for user 1 missing an answer in the desired output?

Comment: He just decided to answer 2 of the three questions.. Just a scenario that could happen.. Empty cells would be ok..  or "Empty" as a state or so alsofine

Comment: Will there always be rows of 3 per user even if they didn't complete a question?

Comment: Ok. I have a solution for you to try.

Comment: Yeah that's fine. In this case those corresponding cells would be empty.. Btw.. this time a screenshot without errors 
https://prnt.sc/hv4fqy

Comment: Curious to your solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming question text remains constant try the following and feedback on any problems. I have used the example from your screen shot link.

[image: Data layout]

New query > from table >

[image: Data from table]

Then pivot question column using answer column as values as ensure aggregation method is max.

[image: Pivot answer]

Check if output is as expected (duplicates are removed)

[image: Result]

Comment: This is already a very good solution! Thanks for that! However, this method only saves 1 "user 1" line with the second answering for the first two questions, and the only answering for the third one. I can definitely proceed with this method though so I reaaallyy appreciate it!

If you would have a method for 2 lines for "user 1" that would be even better!

Comment: I will need to have a tinker. Do you mind if i post back later if i make progress as have some work to do at present?

Comment: got a solution @QHarr? In [this example](http://prntscr.com/lisptq) my users give multiple answers to the same question. It would be wonderful if this question has 1 column, with multiple values in the same column.. looking forward to a solution, really struggling :)

Comment: I completely forgot. Sorry. Do you want me to look at that linked example?

Comment: do not feel sorry at all!!! Yes [this example](http://prntscr.com/liuae0) looks a bit nicer.. so what happens is that 2 same questions are answered over and over again.. I wish both questions had their own columns and that the rows beneath define the answers.. Very much appreciated!

Comment: sure :) Thanks :)

Comment: I fixed it by following this tutorial: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3358-excel-transpose-unique-values.html#a1

Comment: However I wish there was a simpler way of doing this (as I have to instruct customers to use this)

Comment: Congrats! Thank you for the link.